# How to get notified when a script didn't run

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script that runs on a machine (called lazyguy) that is usually turned off.  Every night, lazyguy wakes up at a known time programmed in the BIOS, does a bunch of processing and inserts data to its Postgres database.  Then, it goes to sleep (database and all).

How can get notified when the script did NOT run?  Ideally, I'd like to get an email notification if nothing was inserted to the database or if the script exited with a non-zero return value.  I definitely need to check for both conditions in case lazyguy ignored his alarm and slept in..again.

I have another machine (taskmaster) that is always running but has limited resources.  Some thoughts:

- Have lazyguy send some sort of message to taskmaster to indicate that he finished his chores (maybe with a count of rows inserted).  Then, taskmaster will check for his report everyday at a certain time.  If it's not there, email me and I'll send the goons to beat up lazyguy.
- Have taskmaster wakeup lazyguy directly with a WakeOnLan packet, wait two minutes, run the script via ssh, and check the number of rows in the database for the day.  If anything goes bad, email me.

Which approach is better?  Is there an easier way to do this?  Which technologies would you use?  I'm thinking maybe some mix of crontab, mailx, logger, and maybe rsyslog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would prefer your first, more decentralized method (e.g. lazyguy would do some request on a simple HTTP server running on taskmaster after successful job, the server would update the timestamp stored on the disk, which would be checked by cron script), but the the second one has an advantage - when you decide to change the lazyguy scheduling (and so a check scheduling), you would do it from a single place - taskmaster.

Comment: Yeah, I'm torn on the two architectures myself.  I think I like centralized just so I don't have to mess with the BIOS to set the schedule.  Plus, If properly implemented, I don't have to mess with the possibility of taskmaster checking too soon for the "report".

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned this yet: When a script run from cron exits abnormally, it sends an email to the mail address specified in /etc/crontab. It includes all output of the script.

Comment: how would you then distinguish if it exitted normally vs not at all?

Comment: @mykhal: If it fails to run, the email says so. If cron is not running crontab entries, then someone else is very very wrong.

Comment: I was actually thinking about that in the back of mind.  However, cron doesn't do that for me anymore on that machine.  I'll have to look into why.

Comment: You may need to set up sendmail and define the mail user in crontab

Answer (score 0):

if lazyguy can print out something to a file after all of his chores are done, then it would be great.

- - - - - rm -rf /tmp/lazyguy.log; /lazyguy.sh > /tmp/lazyguy.log

then have another script run at another time to check if lazyguy did finished, still running or did not run at all.

to check your if lazyguy you can do something like

`checkamdump(){

while ps ax | grep -v grep | grep "lazyguy.sh" > /dev/null

do

sleep $SLEEPTIMEOUT

done

}`

Also, you can check lazyguy.log by adding this to your script


`FILESIZE=stat -c %s /tmp/lazyguy.log

if [ $FILESIZE -gt 0 ]

then

mailx -s "Lazyguy is really lazy" alerts@main.com < /tmp/lazyguy.log

fi`


Hope this helps, add your comment if you have any other questions

Comment: Since lazyguy goes to sleep, the job on lazyguy has to transfer the "I did it" information to some other less snoozy machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can send your self an email through a command line 
with the mail command. Use this link  http://www.amirwatad.com/blog/archives/2009/03/21/send-email-from-the-command-line-using-gmail-account/ to set it up. you can set a special account for this.